# Rails helper method: Nested hash to nested HTML list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to write a Rails helper method to convert a nested hash into a nested HTML list.

For example:

```
{
  :parent => "foo",
  :children => [
    {
      :parent => "bar",
      :children => [
        {
          :parent => "baz",
          :children => []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

should become:

```
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <ul>
    <li>bar</li>
    <ul>
      <li>baz</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

The hash may have any number of levels, and any number of parents per level.

What is the best way to achieve this please?

Comment: Render a partial that takes the data and renders the *same* partial for the sub-items.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make a recursive method to render to hash to a nested set of lists. Place this in your relevant helper:

```
def hash_list_tag(hash)
  html = content_tag(:ul) {
    ul_contents = ""
    ul_contents << content_tag(:li, hash[:parent])
    hash[:children].each do |child|
      ul_contents << hash_list_tag(child)
    end

    ul_contents.html_safe
  }.html_safe
end
```

Comment: I've created a helper method as you said and inserted this erb code `<div>
  <% hash_list_tag Tag.hash_tree do |tag| %>
    <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.name) %>
  <% end %>
</div>` in index.html.erb file but no list is generated. So far, I've created Post and Tag models and used Closure Tree to create Tag hierarchies.

Comment: Thanks @Zach kemp for your post. My question is why we can not  use "div" instead of "ul".

Comment: @Gagan, you can use `div` if that's what you need. This particular question asked about `ul`.

Comment: @ZachKemp When i use div instead of ul. it does not work properly.
`<div>
<li>foo</li>
</div>
<div>
<li>bar</li>
</dv>
<div>
<li>baz</li>
</div>

`
This is the output when i use div.

Comment: notice that you dont actually need this `html = ` assignment

Answer (score 1):

Zach Kemp's answer very effectively addresses the question. If you are looking for something a bit more generic (a nested hash for which you will not know the key names), as I was, the following module may be helpful (also at https://github.com/sjohnson/auto_hash_display with more details):

```
module HashFormatHelper
  # These methods add classes to the HTML structure that are defined in Bootstrap (and can be defined for other CSS frameworks)
  def format_hash(hash, html = '')
    hash.each do |key, value|
      next if value.blank?
      if value.is_a?(String) || value.is_a?(Numeric)
        html += content_tag(:ul, class: 'list-group') {
          ul_contents = ''
          ul_contents << content_tag(:li, content_tag(:h3, key.to_s.underscore.humanize.titleize), class: 'list-group-item')
          ul_contents << content_tag(:li, value, class: 'list-group-item')

          ul_contents.html_safe
        }
      elsif value.is_a?(Hash)
        html += content_tag(:ul, class: 'list-group') {
          ul_contents = ''
          ul_contents << content_tag(:li, content_tag(:h3, key.to_s.underscore.humanize.titleize), class: 'list-group-item')
          inner = content_tag(:li, format_hash(value), class: 'list-group-item')
          ul_contents << inner

          ul_contents.html_safe
        }
      elsif value.is_a?(Array)
        html += format_array(value)
      else
        Rails.logger.info "Unexpected value in format_hash: #{value.inspect}"
        Rails.logger.info "value type: #{value.class.name}"
      end
    end
    html.html_safe
  end

  def format_array(array, html = '')
    array.each do |value|
      if value.is_a?(String)
        html += content_tag(:div, value).html_safe
      elsif value.is_a?(Hash)
        html += format_hash(value)
      elsif value.is_a?(Array)
        html += format_array(value)
      else
        Rails.logger.info "Unexpected value in format_array: #{value.inspect}"
        Rails.logger.info "value type: #{value.class.name}"
      end
    end
    html
  end
end
```

This code can also be used to display XML by setting the hash value equal to Hash.from_xml(your_xml_data) and then passing that in to format_hash(hash).

Please note that the from_xml method may strip off XML tag attributes, so it works best for XML that doesn't have attributes.