# Implementing Rails helper method: Nested hash tree to nested HTML list

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to convert a nested hash tree to nested HTML list. So far I've created Post and Tag model and implemented hierarchy to the Tag model using [Closure Tree](https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree#nested-hashes) .

Following is the helper method I've found from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904772/rails-helper-method-nested-hash-to-nested-html-list) to make a recursive method to render hash to a nested set of list:

```
def hash_list_tag(hash)
  html = content_tag(:ul) {
    ul_contents = ""
    ul_contents << content_tag(:li, hash[:parent])
    hash[:children].each do |child|
      ul_contents << hash_list_tag(child)
    end

    ul_contents.html_safe
  }.html_safe
end
```

I just inserted this code to my helper section (application_helper.rb) without changing anything.

Afterwards, I embedded the following inside the view page(index.html.erb) to render a hash to a nested HTML list:

```
<div>
  <% hash_list_tag Tag.hash_tree do |tag| %>
    <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.name) %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

However, I received this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
    1: 
    2: 
    3: <div>
    4:   <% hash_list_tag Tag.hash_tree do |tag| %>
    5:     <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.name) %>
    6:   <% end %>
    7: </div>
  app/helpers/application_helper.rb:14:in `block in hash_list_tag'
  app/helpers/application_helper.rb:11:in `hash_list_tag'
  app/views/posts/index.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_posts_index_html_erb__1316616690179183751_70207605533880'
```

Comment: Sadly I'm not at a level to write my own helper methods, I found this helper method from another post. This is the link <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904772/rails-helper-method-nested-hash-to-nested-html-list>. I'll greatly appreciate if you could help me what I should do to fix this or advise me if there's other way to call the descendants of root nodes.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
hash[:children].each do |child|
```

and there are no children, the result is a nil, which has no method called each. (Read the error message). So you need to check for this case:

```
if !(hash[:children].nil?)
  hash[:children].each do |child|
```

Comment: This removed the error, but I don't see my list on the index page. I'm  double checked from 'rails console' that Tag.hash_tree generates nested hash.

Answer (score 0):

With closure tree you dont get hash with :parent and :children keys. 
Below code will solve your issue.

```
html = content_tag(:ul) {
    ul_contents = ""
    hash.each do |key, value|
      ul_contents << content_tag(:li, key)
      if value.present?
        value.each do |child|
          ul_contents << hash_list_tag(child)
        end
      end
    end

    ul_contents.html_safe
  }.html_safe
```